# Floodfill part of an Image

Tags: delphi, flood-fill

I have an image like bellow 
[image: original image]

i want to make the image become like
[image: image result]

I already make the code, like this :

```
var
  Tx,Ty, R,G,B,A, posX, posY : integer;
begin
  posX :=-1; posY := -1;
  for Ty:= 0 to Image1.Height-1 do
  begin
    for Tx:= 0 to Image1.Width-1 do
    begin
      R:= GetRValue(image1.Canvas.Pixels[Tx, Ty]);
      G:= GetGValue(image1.Canvas.Pixels[Tx, Ty]);
      B:= GetBValue(image1.Canvas.Pixels[Tx, Ty]);
      A:= (R + G + B) Div 3;

      if (A > 50) then
      begin
         Image1.Canvas.Pixels[Tx,Ty] := rgb(255,255,255);
      end else
      begin
         Image1.Canvas.Pixels[Tx,Ty] := rgb(0,0,0);
         if (posX < 0) then
         begin
           posX := Tx;
           posY := Ty;
         end;
      end;
   end;
  end;
 Image1.Canvas.Brush.Style := bsSolid;
 Image1.Canvas.Brush.Color := clred;
 Image1.Canvas.FloodFill(posX,posY,clBlack,fsSurface);
end;
```

My coding above only can make the floodfill only for the dot. 
[image: my coding result]

how can i make floodfill like the result image? thanks

Comment: You can fill a region with `FillRgn` but how are you going to define the region? My instincts tell me that you are attempting to solve the problem the wrong way. We could help you solve the problem that way, but it would make more sense, in my view, to help you find a better solution.

Comment: You seem to misunderstand what "flood-fill" means. Don't you get the same results when you use the equivalent tool in your image-editing program, like MS Paint? Your code turns light-colored pixels white and dark-colored pixels black, and then you want to change the black pixels to be red. Why bother making them black first? Just change them to red directly.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that you want to replace all dark pixels with red, and all light pixels with white.  Your code is almost there.  Instead of replacing the dark pixels with black, and then floodfill-ing the black pixels, why not just set them directly to red, and forget about the floodfill altogether.

Just replace the `RGB(0,0,0)` in your code with `clRed`, and remove all the code related to the floodfill.

I should try to explain what floodfill is and why it didn't do what you expected. A floodfill changes the color of all similarly-colored, contiguously-adjacent pixels to the selected seed pixel.  That is to say, it starts with the pixel you select, in your case, (posX,posY). It processes that pixel, and then all the same-colored pixels adjacent to that pixel, and then the same-colored pixels adjacent to *those* pixels, and so on.

In this case, you begin the floodfill at a point in the dot over the letter i.  The "flood" spreads outwards from that point, from black-pixel to black-pixel, until it hits the border formed by the white pixels.  The flood never reaches the main body of the letter i because those points are not contiguous to the seed point.

This link from Wikipedia has more explanation and some animations that may help you understand. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill

Comment: Sorry if my post make you all seems misunderstood. First I change the color into black or binerization because if the image you upload not a black/white image, you must change into black/white first. Second, why I do flood fill is to check, how many object is there in the image. for example with the image i post, if the first floodfill done to check the dot, so there is a counter to check that have 1 object, then the second floodfill check if there's another object or not.

Comment: So you want to count the number of "objects" in the picture using floodfill.  This is what I suggest.  You can keep the code that loops through all the pixels, changing them to black or white.  Now loop through all the pixels again.  This time, every time you find a black pixel, increment the counter, and do a floodfill starting at that pixel, changing black to red.

Comment: By the way, you mention that you are uploading the image.  I'm curious, why are you uploading the image, and where is it being uploaded to?

Comment: okay i'll try your suggestion first. whether it's work or not i'll post later. I use opendialog for load image in delphi. so it can load image whatever i want.